# Streaming video for flash/html5 player using catalyst framework

Tags: perl, streaming, video-streaming, jwplayer, catalyst

I'm developing a site with serves several videos online, using the Catalyst (A perl MVC framework) and the JWplayer, and I need a stable way of stream the videos to the client player with the capability of start the video from a random point.

I searched the web for some ways to do it but I cannot find a simple way of implementing it in Catalyst (RTMP or HTTP Pseudostreaming). The only simple example that i found was a old Catalyst script streaming an MP3 (http://dev.catalyst.perl.org/repos/Catalyst/trunk/examples/Streaming/lib/Streaming.pm) but I didn't know if that will work as expected if I apply that technique to videos.

What would be a good approach to serve online videos in Catalyst/Perl in a non complicated way? Or what is the recommended way to do it?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I use apache with x_send_file plugin to deliver webm videos (using range byte seek) and Amazon cloud front to deliver mp4 videos and streaming with mp4.

Edit:
Ended using a Wowza Streaming Server with a custom plugin to communicate securely with Catalyst. There is no reliable way of streaming video without a dedicated video server, especially for business.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, as I'm currently stuck on this, as well.

If the files are already in FLV format, then the Static::Simple plugin will work just fine.  I've tested it with a file in the root/static/ directory and with the `$c->serve_static_file` method.  Below is my jwplayer setup (wrapped in JQuery's ready function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[% c.uri_for('/static/js/mediaplayer-5.10') %]/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        'flashplayer': "[% c.uri_for('/static/js/mediaplayer-5.10/player.swf') %]",
        'id': 'playerID',
        'width': '480',
        'height': '270',
        'file': "[% c.uri_for('/download') %]/dump/ffs/root/static/transcode_jEfhmk.flv"
    }); 
});
</script>
```

If the file is in another format, you'll need to transcode it.  The following is my current attempt.  It transcodes it just fine and you can even stream the file to a download, but I'm having trouble getting jwplayer to play from the transcoded stream.

```
use IPC::Open3;

#path comes in as /flv/path/to/file.avi
sub index :Path :Args {
    my ( $self, $c, @path ) = @_; 
    @path = grep($_ ne '..', @path);
    my $path = join('/',@path);
    my $abs_path = $c->config->{'serve_dir'} . '/';
    $abs_path .= join("/", @path);

    if (-r $abs_path){
        my ($stdin, $stdout, $stderr, $pid);
    #avconv 
    # -i input_file
    # -b:v video bitrate
    # -s video size
    # -r video framerate
    # -an no audio (having trouble with the audio settings)
    # -f format
    # pipe:1 send transcoded video to STDOUT
        $pid = open3($stdin, $stdout, $stderr, "avconv -i \"$abs_path\" -b:v 600k -s 320x240 -r 25 -f flv -an pipe:1");

        $c->response->content_type("video/x-flv");
        $c->response->header('Content-Disposition' => "filename=transcode.flv");
        my $chunk_size = 1048576;
        do {
            read( $stdout, my $buffer, $chunk_size );
            $c->write( $buffer );
        } while (kill(0, $pid)); #loop while transcoding process is alive
    }
}
```

To add pseudo-streaming, you'll need to make a controller that looks for the start query parameter, then seek to it, and send the `$c->response->body` to the file handle.

```
open(my $fh, "<", $path);
binmode($fh);
if ($c->req->param('start')){
    seek($fh, $c->req->param('start'), 0); 
}
$c->response->body($fh);
```

One caveat: the video must have the key frames in the metadata for jwplayer to be able to seek.

From jwplayer's [HTTP streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming) page:

*Note: Some FLV encoders do not include seekpoints metadata when encoding videos. 
Without this data, HTTP Pseudostreaming will not work. If you suspect your videos to not have metadata, use our [Metaviewer plugin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/64/Metaviewer) to inspect the video. There should be a seekpoints or keyframes list. If it is not there, use the FLVMDI tool to parse your FLV videos and inject this metadata.*

Comment: The Static::Simple plugin will provide video (using the FLV format) to the player in any start position the player request? I didn't have time to test it today but i will test it and post the results!

Comment: Looks like I was wrong.  My video buffered instantly so I didn't notice you couldn't seek passed the buffered part.  Looks like we might need to implement [pseudo-streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming#mechanism), catch the start parameter, and seek to it like in the Streaming.pm. At least it's in bytes.  Heh.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm still searching a stable and simple way of doing the streaming. If i succeed i will put the how to here!